# Is the function of Displayed Math Gone?

Tags: discussion, soft-question

Hello There,

This might not be the place to ask this question, but I would not know where else to being that it pertains to SE in particular. I was wondering is the functionality of the displayed math mode command gone for use here. The command in which I am talking about is below:

```
                                 \[...\]
```

It seems to work now I see as sample code but not as a functional math related command.

Any explanations on this will be appreciated.

Comment: @Qwirk: Is Meta just for discussions and questions in general?

Comment: meta.math.SE is for discussions and questions *about* and *relating to* math.SE that do not belong on the main site (being questions that are not mathematical or relating to mathematics itself) such as this one. See the [faq](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/faq) for details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question should be asked on [meta.math.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/).

For the sake of having a quick answer: You need to use `\\[...\\]`

For instance, writing `\\[ \int e^x. \\]` gives

\[ \int e^x. \]

Alternatively, you can also use `$$...$$`. You'll surely get more detailed information shortly.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what it needs to be.

Answer (score 5):

The strings

`\[`

and

`\(`

have meaning in Markdown, per https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Thus, you must escape them. Or to keep it simple, use `$` (inline) and `$$` (block) syntax.

Answer (score 3):

```
\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}
```

also works.

\begin{equation} \int e^{-x^2/2} dx \end{equation}